# Tails time synchronization wrong (1 hour early). Has this any practical meaning?

Tags: tails, time

I just installed tails and after connecting to WiFi I get a pop up message saying that Tor needs to sync system time to work properly. After a while I get a new pop up message confirming that the time is synced and Tor is ready to use.

But the time is wrong (1 hour early). Has this any practical meaning? Is everything working properly even though the time is wrong?

I have tested the connection with check.torproject.com and get the following message:
"Congratulations. This browser is configured to use Tor"

Thanks for help on this matter.

Answer (score 1):

Tails sets the timezone to UTC, this means all Tails users appear to be in the same timezone which helps resist fingerprinting (as your timezone relates to your geographic location).

You will probably be in a UTC+1 timezone for your localtime, which is why Tails looks to be 1 hour early but functions normally.

The tails developers are looking into having a custom time display so users can see their localtime (while the system itself is still set to UTC).